apt-get update: An error occurred during the signature verification (for screenrec)
I get this when I run sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:7 https://screenrec.com/download/ubuntu stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                  
Hit:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease                                     
Hit:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease               
Hit:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease            
Hit:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:7 https://screenrec.com/download/ubuntu stable InRelease
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 489A0E7BA517FE30
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://screenrec.com/download/ubuntu stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 489A0E7BA517FE30
W: Failed to fetch https://screenrec.com/download/ubuntu/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 489A0E7BA517FE30

I tried removing and re-installing screenrec but it still gives me that issue, even after using purge
Is there any way to solve this problem? 
I am running-
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


This error will occur if you don't have the repo key for that repository.

You are using https://screenrec.com as a source for installing files, a repository or PPA. Linux is rather picky about installing files from outside sources, which is a security feature.
If you wish, you can add a PPA, effectively allowing you to trust that source implicitly. The positive aspect is that allows you to install third-party applications. The negative is that you place trust in that third party, and accept their files without any check.
To add ScreenRec as PPA, follow their directions:
sudo wget -q -O - https://screenrec.com/download/pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://screenrec.com/download/ubuntu stable main'

The first step fetches the key used to recognize that repository, the second adds screnrec.com as a trusted repository of files.
If you perform those two steps, and ScreenRec update fails again, then that repository's key is wrong -- it might be outdated or revoked.

Thanks, dunno what I did but that error stopped coming after a few days
